# Cálculo de diárias de hotel em aplicação MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Recentemente comecei a programar em MVC e estou cheio de dúvidas.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de reserva de hotéis e depois de passar 3 dias tentando calcular o custo total de uma reserva sem êxito, resolvi pedir ajuda com o código porque estou com dúvidas se estou criando o `Controller` e as `Views` corretamente.

Neste sistema tenho cadastrado 4 hotéis diferentes, cada hotel tem vários tipos de quarto e cada quarto tem uma diária diferente, sendo que estas diárias variam
conforme o período do ano (temporadas) e são calculadas com base em uma data inicial e final, se o dia cai numa sexta-feira ou num sábado, se a reserva é por uma semana ou por um mês.

Ou seja, preciso de calcular o dia a dia entre a data de chegada e a data da saída, verificar se o dia está dentro de uma temporada e se é sexta-feira ou um sábado, etc. e no final ter o preço total da reserva.

O cadastramento de hotéis, tipos de quarto, temporadas (baixa temporada, Natal, Verão, Inverno, Páscoa, etc) funcionam perfeitamente até ao ponto em que um botão `Calcular reserva` é chamado.
Eu não estou conseguindo fazer o cálculo nem retornar alguma `View` mostrando o **Total da Reserva**. Segue o código:

Classes:

```
public class Hotel
{
    public int HotelId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Quarto> Quarto { get; set; }
}

public class Quarto
{
    public int QuartoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public int HotelId { get; set; }

    public virtual Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Temporada> Temporada { get; set; }
}

public class Temporada
{
    public int TemporadaId { get; set; }
    public string NomeTemporada { get; set; }

    public DateTime Chegada { get; set; }

    public DateTime Saida { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = " Diaria Fora de Temporada")]
    public decimal DiariaForaTemporada{ get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "$ Diaria Temporada ")]
    public decimal DiariaTemporada { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "$ Diaria Sexta/Sabado")]
    public decimal DiariaSabado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "$ Diaria Semana")]
    public decimal Diaria Semana { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "$ Diaria Mes")]
    public decimal DiariaMes { get; set; }

    public int QuartoId { get; set; }

    public int HotelId { get; set; }

    public virtual Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
    public virtual Quarto Quarto { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
// GET: Admin/Temporada

public ActionResult TotalReserva()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Admin/Temporada
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ViewResult ValorDiaria(Temporada TotalReserva)
{
    var dChegada = new DateTime(Chegada);
    var dSaida = new DateTime(Saida);
    var vlrdiaria = 0;

    for (var curData = dChegada; curDate < dSaida; curDate = curDate.AddDays(1))
    {
        vlrdiaria += Convert.ToInt32(ValorDiaria(curDate));
    }

    return View(TotalReserva);
}

private ViewResult View(Func<ViewResult> ValorDiaria)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static int ValrDiaria(DateTime Date)
{
    var temporada = new List<Temporada>();

    foreach (var temporada in temporadas)

    if (temporada.ContainsDate(Date))
    {

        if (Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sexta) || (Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sexta)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(temporada.DiariaSabado);
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(temporada.DiariaTemporada);
        }
    }
    return Convert.ToInt32(temporada.DiariaBasica;
}
```

Comment: Seu código nao devia nem rodar, está com erro de sintaxe  na penúltima linha return Convert.ToInt32(temporada.DiariaBasica; @Jose Silveira

Comment: O erro de sintax aconteceu na hora da postagem da pergunta. Na aplicação está correto. De qualquer forma, obrigado por sua resposta.

Comment: Não entendi qual é a dificuldade. Aqui: `vlrdiaria += Convert.ToInt32(ValorDiaria(curDate));`, este valor é computado mas não vai pra lugar algum.

Comment: Não consigo fazer retornar nenhum valor e consequentemente obter o valor total da reserva. Preciso calcular dia a dia, identificando se o valor para o dia é diária básica, diária de quinta-feira ou sexta-feira ou diária de fimdesemana e depois somar tudo, acho que grande parte do código está com erro.  Mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo identificar estes erros.

Answer (score 1):

Há vários erros no seu código, mas imagino que você precisa de uma rotina de cálculo em Ajax. [Montei essa prova de contexto pra ajudar](https://github.com/cigano/ExemploAjax).

Em primeiro lugar, defina um `ReservasViewModel`:

```
public class ReservasViewModel
{
    public int QuartoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataChegada { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataSaida { get; set; }
    public Decimal ValorReserva { get; set; }
}
```

Depois, um *Controller* com uma *Action* inicial, apenas para exibir uma *View* desta *ViewModel*:

```
public class ReservasController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Reservas
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Quartos = db.Quartos.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    ...
}
```

A *View*:

```
@model ExemploAjax.ViewModels.ReservasViewModel
@using ExemploAjax.Models

<h1>Reservas</h1>


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuartoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QuartoId, ((IEnumerable<Quarto>)ViewBag.Quartos).Select(q => new SelectListItem
       {
           Text = q.Nome,
           Value = q.QuartoId.ToString(),
           Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.QuartoId == q.QuartoId)
       }), "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuartoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataChegada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataChegada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataChegada, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataSaida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataSaida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataSaida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorReserva, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValorReserva, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValorReserva, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<button id="Calcular">Calcular</button>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Calcular").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("CalcularReserva", "Reservas")",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        DataSaida: $("#DataSaida").val(),
                        DataChegada: $("#DataChegada").val(),
                        QuartoId: $("#QuartoId").val()
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#ValorReserva").val(result.ValorReserva);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Repare que chamo um método Ajax ao clicar no botão "Calcular":

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Calcular").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("CalcularReserva", "Reservas")",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                DataSaida: $("#DataSaida").val(),
                DataChegada: $("#DataChegada").val(),
                QuartoId: $("#QuartoId").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#ValorReserva").val(result.ValorReserva);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Para esta chamada, é preciso criar um método no *controller* `ReservasController` assim:

```
    public JsonResult CalcularReserva(ReservasViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var dChegada = viewModel.DataChegada;
        var dSaida = viewModel.DataSaida;
        var vlrdiaria = 0;

        for (var curDate = dChegada; curDate < dSaida; curDate = curDate.AddDays(1))
        {
            vlrdiaria += Convert.ToInt32(ValorDiaria(curDate));
        }

        return Json(new { ValorReserva = vlrdiaria }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private static int ValorDiaria(DateTime Date)
    {
        if ((Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday) || (Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
        {
            return 100;
        }

        return 80;
    }
```

Repare também que coloquei uma versão simplificada de `ValorDiaria` porque a sua versão não faz sentido.